# What is the thing after the outflow of the washing drum called?

Tags: washing-machine

Below is a nice view of the inside of the **pipe between the washing drum and the drain pump** (looking in the direction of the washing drum). I just found a popsicle stick and a few socks in there.

I was wondering what the black rubber balloon thing right below the outflow of the washing drum is called, what it's used for and how it works? It's soft (has air inside), has a hole at the bottom and is somehow attached right below the outflow of the washing drum so it can move up and down.

[image: black balloon thing]

(Washing machine is a Siemens IQ500)

Comment: That pic needs one of those 'click here to unblur' warnings ... it's traumatic to look at so soon after eating ...

Comment: When you say drain pipe, does this have a sump pump attached to it, or does this drain directly to a sewer or septic system?

Comment: It sounds like a check valve to me , not sure the picture helped in this case.

Comment: @IronEagle sorry I meant to say "drain pump", not drain pipe (edited now)... so on the photo there is the outflow of the washing drum (ahead) -> pipe -> drain pump (behind).

Comment: @EdBeal I guess that might make sense.. since there's a hole on the bottom it fills with air and starts floating once there's water in the pipe, it closes the outflow of the washing drum and prevents all that nasty stuff and popsicle sticks from swimming back up into the washing drum? I guess that might be it - feel free to post an answer.